# Running multiple applications from Qt Creator

Tags: qt-creator

Is there any way to run two applications simultaneously from Qt creator? Basically I am trying to run the UI app developed inside a skin from Qt creator which will need qvfb frame buffer tool to run too for the skin file to launch. I tried adding both UI app and qvfb to custom run settings, but only one would run at a time. Is there any other possible method?

Answer (score 0):

You run QVFB from the bin folder of your Qt installation first outside of QtCreator

`PATH_TO_QT/bin/qvfb`  and then you run the UI app with "-qws -display QVFb:0" as run parameters  
In QtCreator go to "Projects" on the side bar then click "Run Settings" and add `-qws -display QVFb:0`   
to the arguments field